# Find file name, assign to variable and run perl script with variable in windows batch file

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, variables

I am trying to search a specified directory and find a file that matches the file mask: Teal*csv and then assign that to a variable (with and without the file extension) and reference those variables in the parameters for the Perl script.

```
set FILEPATH=\\DBserver\files\outgoing\Temp\Teal*.csv
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%FILEPATH%") do (
  set "FILEFULLNAME=%%~nxA"
  set "FILEMASK=%%~nA"
  set "FILEEXT=%%~xA"
)

perl \\DBserver\scripts\splitfileFINAL.pl \\DBserver\files\outgoing\Temp\%FILEFULLNAME 300000 %FILEMASK
```

Perl script has 3 parameters: 1st file to be split, 2nd number of rows per file and 3rd filename without file extension

Comment: Is the last line `\\DBserver\...` part of the script? did you mean `%FILEFULLNAME%` rather than `%FILEFULLNAME`, and same for `FILEMASK`?

Answer (score 0):

To reference the value of a batch variable, you need to use `%varname%`, hence

```
... %FILEFULLNAME% 300000 %FILEMASK%
```

should cure your (unstated) problem, given that the variables are correctly established.

Answer (score 0):

As Magoo stated in his answer, you need to put `%` on both ends of the environment variable when you want to expand it.

But if you want to iterate files in a folder, then you want to use the simple FOR, not FOR /F.

Also, I don't see why you need environment variables at all. You can simply use the FOR variables directly.

Finally, the %%A will include the full path. There is no need to hard code the file path in the body of the loop.

```
@echo off
set "SCRIPT=\\DBserver\scripts\splitfileFINAL.pl"
set "FILEPATH=\\DBserver\files\outgoing\Temp\Teal*.csv"
for %%A in ("%FILEPATH%") do perl "%SCRIPT%" "%%F" 300000 "%%~nA"
```

If your perl script creates additional csv files within the same folder, then those new files could potentially be picked up by the FOR loop. If this is the case, then you do need to switch to FOR /F and process a DIR command, so that the complete list of files is buffered before any processing is begun. Now the full path is not listed within %%A, so you do need to include it within the body.

```
@echo off
set "SCRIPT=\\DBserver\scripts\splitfileFINAL.pl"
set "FILEPATH=\\DBserver\files\outgoing\Temp\"
set "FILEMASK=Teal*.csv"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d "%FILEPATH%%FILEMASK%") do (
  perl "%SCRIPT%" "%FILEMASK%%%A" 300000 "%%~nA"
)
```

Comment: Thank you. The biggest thing I am struggling with is how to find the file. The file name is incremented per day.. so where the * (Teal*.csv) is located is the current date or a date of the file. I am trying to break up this file to then have my FTP client pull it to my website. How can I get the batch script to look in that directory to find a file like Teal_20161027.csv and then have the perl script split that